# How to get recent conversations Laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I can already do this using the follow SQL command

```
SELECT * FROM users AS u INNER JOIN messages AS m ON u.ID IN (m.senderID, m.recipientID) WHERE u.ID <> $userID GROUP BY u.ID ORDER BY m.created_at DESC
```

How do I convert it to Laravel query builder, I have a Message model and User model

Comment: Always put some tried code in the question it will help you out  easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do like this :

```
$users  = User::join('messages', 'users.ID', '=', 'messages.user_id')
            ->whereIn('users.ID',['messages.senderId', 'messages.recipientID'])
            ->where('users.ID', '!=', $userID)
            ->groupBy('users.ID')
            ->orderBy('created_at','DESC')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

$UserMessage = Message::where('from_user', $user_id)
->orWhere('to_user', $user_id)->latest()->get();

```
    $usersChat = $UserMessage->map(function ($conversation) {
        if ($conversation->from_user === auth()->id()) {
            return $conversation->receiver;
        }
        return $conversation->sender;
    })->unique();

    return   $usersChat;
```

and in message model

```
public function sender() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'from_user');
}

public function receiver() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'to_user');
}
```